# setting a thumbnail image for pdf file when seen in explorer file list

Tags: c#, windows, pdf, thumbnails, windows-explorer

**1)**
I'm trying to set the thumbnail image that you see in explorer for a pdf.
At the moment, all the thumbnails are just the Abode PDF logo ... I'd like to set it to an image of my choice.
I have looked at the Win 7 shell pack api, and cannot find any way to set the image, only ways to extract the (default) image.
Can this even be done, or is it the adobe dll that sets the thumbnail??

**2)**
Also, related I think, is there a way to set the 'explorer star rating' from code?

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Update: Adobe Reader provides this service for Windows Explorer. It may need to be enabled on 64-bit systems via menu Preferences-General-Thumbnails. See this Adobe link for details: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/enable-pdf-thumbnail-preview-windows-explorer.html

Answer (score 0):

For first one, there has to be shell extension that provides thumbnail image (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774614.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969351.aspx)

Check  [this part of code project article series](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide9.aspx) - "A tutorial on writing an extension to customize the icons displayed for a file type"

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd already come across the articles you mention, but I was hoping for a .net/c# solution. While I was researching I found a post from 2005 which said that it was impossible using managed code.... I'd hoped things might have changed.